# Python: question about the loggind module with TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, python-logging

Backgroud: I try to use the loggind module to record my log.

I use `TimedRotatingFileHandler` and set the date suffix `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M` to each log file . However, I noticed that the first log file that be generated by the logging module didn't append the suffix to its file name, how can I fix it or it is inevitable?

[image: file list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the name of the current file in which the logger is writing. The others are the previous.
Here is my code :

```py
import logging
import time
from logging import handlers

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("log", when="s"))

for i in range(10):
    root_logger.warning(i)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

It produced :

- `log.2022-01-27_17-37-33`

  ```
  0
  ```
- `log.2022-01-27_17-37-34`

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ```
- `log.2022-01-27_17-37-35`

  ```
  5
  6
  7
  8
  ```
- `log`

  ```
  9
  ```

When run again, it renamed `log` to `log.2022-01-27_17-37-36` and produced another 4 files, three with a date and the last without.

Comment: Good explanation, thx.